# C# - Korean Encoding

Tags: c#

This might be different with other Korean encoding questions.

There is this site I have to scrape and it's Korean.

An example sentence in their site is this
"개인정보보호를 위해 뒤로가기 버튼 대신 검색결과 화면 상단과 하단의 이전 버튼을 사용하시기 바랍니다."

I am using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to scrape the site.

this is how I retreive the html

-- partial code --

```
using (Stream data = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    response.Append(new StreamReader(data, Encoding.GetEncoding(code), true).ReadToEnd());
}
```

now my problem is, am not getting the correct Korean characters. In my "code" variable, I'm basing the code page here in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx (let me narrow it down).

here are the Korean code pages:
51949, 50225, 20949, 20833, 10003, 949

but am still not getting the correct Korean characters? What you think is the problem?

Comment: What encoding is the page in? Does it have any meta tags? What about the http headers?

Comment: it just head EUC-KR but I already used that name Encoding.GetEncoding("EUC-KR"), and still got the wrong korean character. ?踰?踰?寃쎈ℓ?蹂????댁?? ?ㅼ寃? ???⑸?? 媛?몄蹂대낫?몃? ????ㅻ?媛湲?踰???? 寃?寃곌낵 ?硫???④낵 ??⑥ ?댁 踰?쇱 ?ъ⑺?湲?諛????

Comment: Do you have that code-page installed on the computer that is doing the scraping?

Comment: @reach4thelasers - No need for that. They have nuclear weapons, you know.

Comment: @reach4thelasers LOL. I think in North Korea, they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely that the page is not in a specific Korean encoding, but one of the Unicode encodings.

Try `Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.Default` (UTF-16) instead of the specific code pages. There are also `Encoding.UTF7` and `Encoding.UTF32`, but they are not as common.

To be certain, examine the meta tags and headers for the content-type returned by the server.

---

Update (gleaned from commments):

Since the content-type header is `EUC-KR`, the corresponding codepage is 51949 and this is what you need to use to retrieve the page.

It was not clear that you are writing this out to a file - you need to use the *same* encoding when writing the file out, or convert the `byte[]` from the original to the output file encoding (using [`Encoding.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx)).

Comment: this is the content-type header "Content-Type:text/html; charset=EUC-KR"

Comment: When I used the Default. I get this "쨈챘쨔첵쩔첩쨔첵쩔첩째챈쨍??짚쨘쨍 ?짢?채???철쩔징 쩔?쩍?째??쨩 ?짱쩔쨉??쨈?쨈?. 째쨀???짚쨘쨍쨘쨍?짙쨍짝 ?짠?? 쨉?쨌?째징짹창 쨔철?째 쨈챘쩍? 째?쨩철째찼째첬 ?짯쨍챕 쨩처쨈?째첬 ??쨈??? ???체 쨔철?째?쨩 쨩챌쩔챘??쩍?짹창 쨔?쨋첩쨈?쨈?." --------- UTF 8 is this "占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙占"." -------- UTF7 is the same as the Default ------- UTF32 didn't work at all ----- Unicode crashed my N++ -----

Comment: @JaysonRagasa - How are you saving the file? Using the same encoding?

Comment: 51949 That's the first thing I tried I know that's the correct code page but what I got is this a different characters again plus the site just went to maintenance mode .. darn ..

Comment: I will look onto that after the site goes back to normal. I think that's my problem. LOL

Answer (score 0):

While having exact same issue I've finished it with code below:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DownloadData(URL));
```

This directly transform output for the WebClient GET request to UTF8 encoding.